# ExpandableListView onChildClick not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have writing a mediaplayer app. When clicked on the play list button, ExpandList Activity launches and depending on which child is clicked, it should start my main activity and return the childposition. But it doenst do anything. There is no error or anything. It seems like its not even going into the onChildClick method and I am not sure why. I have looked at many examples and they all seem to have it the same why I have it. I was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code below. Thank you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExpandListActivity extends ExpandableListActivity implements
OnChildClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();
    expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandbleLis.setClickable(true);
    expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    setGroupData();
    setChildGroupData();

    NewAdapter mNewAdapter = new NewAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
    mNewAdapter
    .setInflater(
            (LayoutInflater)       getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
            this);
    expandbleLis.setAdapter(mNewAdapter);

}

public void setGroupData() {
    groupItem.add("TechNology");
    groupItem.add("Mobile");
    groupItem.add("Manufacturer");
    groupItem.add("Extras");
}

ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setChildGroupData() {
    /**
     * Add Data For TecthNology
     */
    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Java");
    child.add("Drupal");
    child.add(".Net Framework");
    child.add("PHP");
    childItem.add(child);

    /**
     * Add Data For Mobile
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Android");
    child.add("Window Mobile");
    child.add("iPHone");
    child.add("Blackberry");
    childItem.add(child);
    /**
     * Add Data For Manufacture
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("HTC");
    child.add("Apple");
    child.add("Samsung");
    child.add("Nokia");
    childItem.add(child);
    /**
     * Add Data For Extras
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Contact Us");
    child.add("About Us");
    child.add("Location");
    child.add("Root Cause");
    childItem.add(child);
}


@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(ExpandListActivity.this, "Clicked On Child",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);

    // Sending childPosition to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);

    Log.println(0, getClass().getName(), "onChildClick inside");

    setResult(100, in);

    startActivity(in);

    // Closing PlayListView
    finish();


    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: I added an answer with the adapter class. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling this activity using `startActivityForResult()`, then correct way to return to calling activity is as follows:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("childPosition", childPosition);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
finish();
```

So you need to remove these lines:

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED MY ISSUE**

I simply added this in the onClick method inside the adapter class and it works. Thank you all.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(activity, AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);   
intent.putExtra("childPosition",childPosition); 
activity.setResult(100, intent);  
activity.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Adapter Class. I have tried adding an intent inside the onClick but its not allowing me to "startActivity();" because I am guessing i am doing this in an adapter class and not an activity class. I am not sure.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
public LayoutInflater minflater;
public Activity activity;

public NewAdapter(ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
    groupItem = grList;
    this.Childtem = childItem;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupItem.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
    }
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```